# How to prove this floor function equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions, elementary-functions

How can I prove the following equation?

$$
  \lfloor nx \rfloor =
  \lfloor x \rfloor + 
  \Big\lfloor x + \frac{1}{n} \Big\rfloor + 
  \Big\lfloor x + \frac{2}{n} \Big\rfloor + 
  \Big\lfloor x + \frac{3}{n} \Big\rfloor + 
  \Big\lfloor x + \frac{4}{n} \Big\rfloor + 
  \Big\lfloor x + \frac{5}{n} \Big\rfloor+ \dotsb + 
  \Big\lfloor x + \frac{n-1}{n} \Big\rfloor
$$
 $n∈N$ and $x∈R$

Comment: Assuming $n \in \mathbb{N}$, induction would be a possible approach.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184361/floor-function-properties-2x-x-x-frac12-and-nx-sum-k) and [other posts linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/184361).

Answer (score 3):

Replacing $x$ by $x':=x+{1\over n}$ adds $1$ on the left hand side. On the right hand side the first term $\lfloor x\rfloor$ disappears, and on the far right the term $\lfloor x+1\rfloor$ appears. It follows that the right hand side increases by $1$ as well.

Therefore it suffices to prove the formula for $0\leq x<{1\over n}$. Inspection immediately reveils that both sides are $=0$ in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a closer look, you will notice that the second term within each floored term will be less than one.
E.g in $$\left\lfloor x+\frac{4}{n}\right\rfloor$$As you can see $\frac{4}{n}$ is less than one.
So, we can conclude that each term will be reduced to $\lfloor x\rfloor$ if $n$ and $x$ are integers.
We will get
$$\lfloor nx\rfloor = n\lfloor x\rfloor$$
Since $n$ and $x$ are integers, we can remove the floor function.
Hence proved.

This identity will not be true for all values of $n$ and $x$ if they can be any number other than integers.  Try putting any fractional value.

Comment: This is a intuitive conclusion and it's not generally true, for example for $x∈R$

Answer (score 1):

Try to rewrite $x$ as
$$x=\lfloor x \rfloor + \frac kn + \alpha$$
where $0\le k<n$ and $0\le\alpha<\frac1n$.