# Show that $\left[\alpha\right]+\left[\alpha+\frac{1}{m}\right]+\cdots + \left[\alpha+\frac{m-1}{m}\right] = \left[m\alpha\right]$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $m$ be a positive integer and let $\alpha$ be a real number. Show that
$$\left[\alpha\right]+\left[\alpha+\frac{1}{m}\right]+\cdots + \left[\alpha+\frac{m-1}{m}\right] = \left[m\alpha\right]$$ where $\left[\ \ \right]$ is the ***integral part*** function.

**Remark:** Attempt to prove this result by induction but  I failed in the inductive step, I have been unable use the induction hypothesis.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184361/floor-function-properties-2x-x-x-frac12-and-nx-sum-k) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/184361)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use induction.

Suppose $\frac{l}{m}\leqslant \alpha-\lfloor \alpha \rfloor<\frac{l+1}{m}, \:0\leqslant l<m,\:l\in \Bbb{N}$. Then 
$$
\:l\leqslant m(\alpha-\lfloor \alpha \rfloor)<l+1 \quad\text{and so}\quad \lfloor m\alpha \rfloor=l+m\lfloor \alpha \rfloor
$$ 
Moreover 
$$
\left\lfloor \alpha +\frac{k}{m}\right\rfloor-\lfloor \alpha \rfloor=\begin{cases}0,\quad0\leqslant k<m-l,\:k\in \Bbb{N}
\\1,\quad m-l\leqslant k<m
\end{cases}
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\left\lfloor \alpha +\frac{k}{m}\right\rfloor=(m-l)\lfloor \alpha \rfloor+ l+l\lfloor \alpha \rfloor=l+m\lfloor \alpha \rfloor=\lfloor m\alpha \rfloor
$$

Answer (score 5):

This is known as [Hermite's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%27s_identity). A nice proof is due to Matsuoka "On a Proof of Hermite's Identity", AMM 71:10 (1964), pp. 1115, DOI: [10.2307/2311413](https://dx.doi.org/10.2307%2F2311413).

Let:

$\begin{align}
   f(x)
      = \lfloor m x \rfloor
   - \lfloor x \rfloor
   - \left\lfloor x + \frac{1}{m} \right\rfloor
   - \left\lfloor x + \frac{2}{m} \right\rfloor
   - \dotsb
   - \left\lfloor x + \frac{m - 1}{m} \right\rfloor
 \end{align}$

For real $\alpha, \beta$ it is $\lfloor \alpha + 1 \rfloor - \lfloor \beta + 1 \rfloor
      = \lfloor \alpha \rfloor - \lfloor \beta \rfloor$, so that:

$\begin{align}
    f\left( x + \frac{1}{m} \right)
      &= \lfloor m x + 1 \rfloor
    - \left\lfloor x + \frac{1}{m}\right\rfloor
    - \left\lfloor x + \frac{2}{m} \right\rfloor
    - \dotsb
    - \left\lfloor x + \frac{m - 1}{m} \right\rfloor
    - \lfloor x + 1 \rfloor \\
      &= \lfloor m x \rfloor
    - \lfloor x \rfloor
    - \left\lfloor x + \frac{1}{m} \right\rfloor
    - \left\lfloor x + \frac{2}{m} \right\rfloor
    - \dotsb
    - \left\lfloor x + \frac{m - 1}{m} \right\rfloor \\
      &= f(x)
  \end{align}$

On the other hand, for $0 \le x < 1 /m$ it is $f(x) = 0$, and so $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$, as was to be proved.