# Is true that $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{[kx]}{k}\leq[nx]$, for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is true that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{[kx]}{k}\leq[nx]$, for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$?

**My work:**

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ be given. For every $k=1,\dots,n$, define $i_k\in\{0,1,\dots,k-1\}$ such that 
$$
[x]+\frac{i_k}{k}\leq x<[x]+\frac{i_k+1}{k}\hspace{20mm} (*).
$$

On one hand, we have that $[kx]=k[x]+i_k$ for every $k=1,\dots,n$.

So  $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{[kx]}{k}=n[x]+\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{i_k}{k}=[nx]+\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{i_k}{k}-i_n$

Thus  $$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{[kx]}{k}\leq[nx]\Leftrightarrow\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{i_k}{k}\leq i_n\,.$$

On the other hand, from $(*)$ is direct that $i_k=[k(x-[x])]$.
Thus  $$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{[kx]}{k}\leq[nx]\Leftrightarrow\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{[k(x-[x])]}{k}\leq [n(x-[x])]\,.$$

In other words, we can assume that $x\in[0,1)$.

Now the questions is:

**Is true that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{[kx]}{k}\leq[nx]$, for every $x\in[0,1)$ and for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$?**

Any simpler approach? Any thoughts?

Comment: You may have already looked at this, but have you tried to show that $$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{i_k}{k}-\frac{i_n}{n}\right)\le0 $$

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales yes, I tried but I don't have a clue how to proceed when one of the terms is positive.

Comment: This might help, where I show that if $n$ is a positive integer
then
$\lfloor nx \rfloor = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \lfloor  x+\frac{k}{n} \rfloor$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184361/floor-function-properties-2x-x-x-frac12-and-nx-sum-k/1678966#1678966

Comment: Also notice that $$i_k\le k\left(x-[x]\right)<i_k+1$$ so in fact $i_k\in\{1,2,\cdots,k-1\}$.

Comment: If you let $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $0<\epsilon<1$ and let $x=m-\epsilon$ then $x-[x]=1-\epsilon$. It is then possible to show that if $p\in\mathbb{Z}^+$  $$\frac{p-1}{\epsilon}<k\le\frac{p}{\epsilon}$$ then $i_k=k-p$. This implies that the $i_k$'s form a monotonic increasing sequence. This might be a useful way of rewriting $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{i_k}{k}$$.

Comment: I meant to say monotonic non-decreasing.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales thanks for the insights, actually there is an explicit expresion for $i_k$ where its non-decreasing behavior is clear. I'm going to update my progress.

Comment: This problem (but with the condition that $x \geq 0$ , though maybe it's not needed...) appeared on the 1981 USAMO (Problem 5) . There are some proofs here : http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h424778p2403926

Comment: @ComplexPhi The truth of the inequality is preserved by replacing $x$ by $x+n$ for any $n$, so we may assume $x$ is positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the function
$$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},f(x)=[nx]-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{[kx]}{k}$$
is right-continuous and $1$-periodic function, so it is enough to prove that $f(x)\ge0$ for $x\in[0,1)$. Note also that the set of points of discontinuity of $f$ on $(0,1)$ is contained in
$$\mathcal{D}=\left\{\frac{p}{q}: 1\le p< q\le n,\gcd(p,q)=1\right\}$$ and that $f$ is constant on any interval contained in $[0,1)\setminus\mathcal{D}$. Therefore, in order to prove that $f(x)\ge0$ on $(0,1)$ it is enough to prove that
$f(r)\ge0$ for $r\in\mathcal{D}$.

Now, consider $r=p/q\in\mathcal{D}$ with $1\le p<q\le n$ and $\gcd(p,q)=1$.
For $k\in\{1,\ldots,q-1\}$ we define
$\phi(k)=pk-q[kr]$. Since $[kr]\le kr<[kr]+1$ we see that $0\le\phi(k)<q$, moreover, if $\phi(k)=0$ for some $k$ we conclude that $q$ must divide $k$, beause
$\gcd(p,q)=1$, which is absurd. Thus $\phi$ takes its values in $\{1,\ldots,q-1\}$. Further, $\phi$ is one to one, because if $\phi(k)=\phi(\ell)$ for some
$1\le k\le\ell<q$ we conclude that $q|(p(\ell-k))$ and again, because $\gcd(p,q)=1$ we see that $q|(\ell-k)$ and this implies that $\ell=k$ because
$0\le \ell-k<q$. Thus, $\phi$ is a permutation on the set $\{1,\ldots,q-1\}$.

Using the AM-GM inequality we have
$$\frac{1}{q-1}\sum_{k=1}^{q-1}\frac{\phi(k)}{k}\ge\left(\prod_{k=1}^{q-1}\frac{\phi(k)}{k}\right)^{1/(q-1)}=1$$
because $\phi(1)\phi(2)\cdot\phi(q-1)=1\cdot 2\cdots(q-1)$.

Thus
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{kp-q[kr]}{k}\ge\sum_{k=1}^{q-1}\frac{kp-q[kr]}{k}\ge q-1
\ge pn-q[nr]$$
Rearranging we get $f(r)\ge0$ which is the desired conclusion. The proof is complete.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using induction from [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h101711p574329) (credit to [Martin R](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/42969/martin-r) for finding this gem in the linked [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4768996)):

> Let $G_{n}(x)$ denote the sum. Add the equations
>
> \begin{eqnarray*}G_{1}(x)&=&\lfloor x\rfloor\\ \ 2(G_{2}(x)-G_{1}(x))&=&\lfloor 2x\rfloor\\ \ \vdots~~~~~~~~~~&=&~~~\vdots\\ \ n(G_{n}(x)-G_{n-1}(x))&=&\lfloor nx\rfloor \end{eqnarray*}
>
> to get
>
> \begin{eqnarray*}nG_{n}(x)&=&\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}G_{k}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lfloor kx\rfloor\\ \ &\leq&\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\lfloor kx\rfloor+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lfloor kx\rfloor~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(\mbox{strong induction})\\ \ &=&\sum_{k=1}^{n}\Bigl(\lfloor kx\rfloor+\lfloor (n-k)x\rfloor\Bigr)\\ \ &\leq&n\lfloor nx\rfloor~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(\mbox{since }\lfloor a\rfloor+\lfloor b\rfloor\leq\lfloor a+b\rfloor\mbox{)}\end{eqnarray*}
>
> which gives the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

$$[nx] \geqslant \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{[kx]}{k} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{kx-\{kx\}}{k} = nx - \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{\{kx\}}{k}\Leftrightarrow$$

$$f(x):=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{\{kx\}}{k} \geqslant \{nx\}=:g(x)$$

$f(0)=\{0\}=0$.

$f,g$ at points of differentiability are growing at a rate of $n$. Hence if the interval $(a,b)$ functions $f,g$ differentiable and $f(a)\geqslant g(a)$, even on this entire interval $f(x)\geqslant g(x)$. It remains to prove the inequality gap in the points. Break points - all rational numbers with denominators $\leqslant n$: $x=\frac{a}{m}$, $a,m$ are relatively prime.

$$f(\frac{a}{m}) \geqslant \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{\{ka/m\}}{k}$$
Numerator - kind of shot $\frac{1}{m},...,\frac{m-1}{m}$, denominators -$1,...,m$. The lowest value of the summation for all permutations of the numerator is obtained when the numerator is proportional to the denominator. So $f(\frac{a}{m})\geqslant \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{k}{km}=1-\frac{1}{m}\geqslant\{n\frac{a}{m}\}$