# Lemma for a question based on Greatest Integer function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality

I was trying to solve the following question.
For a positive real number x, prove that
$$[x]+\frac{[2x]}{2}+\frac{[3x]}{3}+\cdots+\frac{[nx]}{n}\leq [nx]$$where [] represent the Greatest Integer Function.

Here is my approach. I used Hermite's Identity to reduce $[nx]$ to $[x]+[x+\frac{1}{n}]+[x+\frac{2}{n}]+\cdots+[x+\frac{n-1}{n}]$ and came across the following lemma.

Lemma: For positive real x and $k=1,2,\cdots,n$, prove that
$$\left[x+\frac{k-1}{n}\right]\geq \frac{[kx]}{k}$$which solves the question directly

Could anyone please verify this equation. If true, please provide a proof for it as well. I tried using induction but fell short

Thanks a lot for the help!!:)

Comment: Btw I would like a proof or disproof of the Lemma and not the question

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699718/is-true-that-sum-k-1n-frackxk-leqnx-for-every-x-in-mathbbr-an) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true, consider for example $x=\frac{1}{2}$, $n=3$ and $k=2$. Then $$\frac{[kx]}{k}=\frac{1}{2}$$
but$$\left[x+\frac{k-1}{n}\right]=\left[\frac{5}{6}\right]=0$$

Comment: Thanks a lot !!