# floor function algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

prove for all real numbers $x$ we have the following inequality $$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{{\lfloor}kx{\rfloor}}{k} \right)\le {{\lfloor}nx{\rfloor}} $$

i can easily prove for $n=1$,how do i approach for $n=m$ and henceforth $n=m+1$.
Or am i approaching this wrong--by trying with induction??

Comment: Solution on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h101711p574329 – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Clfloor%20kx%20%5Crfloor%7D%7Bk%7D%20%5Cle%20%5Clfloor%20nx%20%5Crfloor%24)

Comment: could you please explain the strong inductive step!!thanks for the link