# Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} [x+\frac{k}{n} ] = [nx]$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$x$ is a positive real number.  $n,\, k$ are positive integers.

I tried showing this by assuming an integer $t$ such that ${x} + t/n < 1$ and ${x} +(t+1)/n > 1$ , where $t \in [0, n-1]$ is an integer.

I got $$\sum = n[x]+(n-1-t) + [x]$$ can't go any further.

Comment: Have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184361/floor-function-properties-2x-x-x-frac12-and-nx-sum-k

Comment: @OlivierOloa the answer that received bounty really illuminated me! Thanks